# How to get pods/binding instance and modify pod data in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have a project to modify the pod, and the modification depends on the pod `nodeName field`. I use the following `webhook` to intercept the pod, but it cannot intercept the `update operation` after the `kube-scheduler allocates the node`

```
apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: MutatingWebhookConfiguration
...
...
  rules:
  - operations: ["UPDATE"]
    apiGroups: [""]
    apiVersions: ["v1"]
    resources: ["pods"]
```

Then I try to use interception `pods/binding`, but when I try to parse the pod binding, I find that the `Binding` type has been deprecated

```
  rules:
  - operations: ["UPDATE"]
    apiGroups: [""]
    apiVersions: ["v1"]
    resources: ["pods/binding"]
```

```
k8s.io/api/core/v1/types.go
// Binding ties one object to another; for example, a pod is bound to a node by a scheduler.
// Deprecated in 1.7, please use the bindings subresource of pods instead.
type Binding struct {
```

But I didn't find `the bindings subresource of pods`. Where is this resource and how to parse it to get the corresponding pod instance?

I really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The API’s structure that we are talking about here is as the following example:

```
APIResponsiveness: Top latency metric: {Resource:pods Subresource:binding Verb:POST …
```

`"bindings subresource of pods"` references to the subresource like `"podAffinity"`, `"nodeAffinity"`, `"nodeSelector"` etc. Take a look into these URLs for more information about this part [Binding [core/v1]](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/rest_api/core/binding-core-v1.html) and [which api can implement“the bindings subresource of pods”](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/1680).

Now, regarding the **POD’s data modification**, first you need to have in mind that we SHOULDN’T edit specifications of an existing POD other than the following ones.

```
*spec.containers[*].image
spec.initContainers[*].image
spec.activeDeadlineSeconds
spec.tolerations*
```

So, to modify the POD’s properties, there are 2 ways to do it:

1.Run the `kubectl edit pod <pod name>` command. You are gonna get the pod specification through an editor. Proceed to edit the properties that you need to. When saving it, you are going to be **denied**, as you are attempting to edit a field on the POD that is not editable, but a copy of the file with the changes you did is going to be created as a YAML file in a temporary location. Then delete the existing POD using command: `kubectl delete pod <pod name>`. Finally, create a new POD with changes using the temporary file `kubectl create -f <newly created yaml file with changes>`.

2.Extract the POD’s definition to a YAML file using `kubectl get pod <pod name> -o yaml > my-new-pod.yaml`
Modify the exported file using an editor (vi editor), save it with `vi my-new-pod.yaml`
Delete the current POD `kubectl delete pod <pod-name>`
And finally create a new pod with the edited file `kubectl create -f my-new-pod.yaml`

Use the following [URL](https://bhavyasree.github.io/kubernetes-CKAD/06.edit-pods-deploys/) as a guide.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I want. As mentioned above, I was expecting to find `the type of pods/bindings`. My ultimate goal is to add `node`-related `labels` before the pod running, I'm currently using `corev1.Bindings` to `decode` the data intercepted by the `webhook`, but this may not be optimal as it's `deprecated`

Comment: As I mentioned before, open the following URL: [Binding (core/v1)](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/rest_api/core/binding-core-v1.html#apiv1namespacesnamespacebindings) 

As that’s the version that you are using, ther URL indicates that as binding was deprecated in version 1.7, you need to use the bindings subresource of pods instead. Then, from the table below and the API endpoints section, that URL explains you how to do it, and finally use the guide in the last URL I gave to you, to edit the deployment of your POD and add the labels that you need.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning:** We can't move running process from one system to another, therefore there is no way of moving an already create pod (in which nodes is already assigned and scheduled by the scheduler) from one node to another.

Here is the step I would follow:

Step 1: Run proxy to your localhost nodes with the port

```
kubectl proxy --port=8080 &
```

Ref links: https://linuxhint.com/execute-curl-with-kubectl/

Step 2: Then you can curl to localhost:8080/api/v1 to test it

```
curl http://localhost:8080/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods
```

You can refers the API links: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/

Step 3: You can modify the pods/$PODNAME/binding which is the API sub-resources of pods. You need to do a POST request on the **http://$SERVER/api/v1/namespaces/dafault/pods/$PODNAME/binding**
For example in case of manual scheduling of pods which is in Pending Status, I used the below

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"apiVersion": "v1", "kind": "Binding", "metadata": { "name": "nginx" }, "target": { "apiVersion": "v1", "kind": "Node", "name": "worker01" }}' http://localhost:8080/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/nginx/binding
```

Ref links: https://www.waytoeasylearn.com/learn/kubernetes-manual-scheduling/

Hope this helps.